# leitor de QRCODE android

Tags: android, qrcode

Galera, to precisando de colocar um leitor de qrcode no meu app android, alguém pode me dar uma dica? Não quero que ele abra outro app, quero que seja dentro do propio app

Comment: Utilize a biblioteca ZXING: https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded

Comment: to usando a biblioteca, vou colocar o código. Até agora tudo certo, ó não to conseguindo fazer com que quando o leitor le o qrcode abra a pagina.. ele só da um "toast"

Comment: Tem este método também muito prático... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=125WPZHxU7E

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para isso, vamos utilizar a biblioteca [ZXING](https://github.com/zxing/zxing)

No **build.gradle**(app) adiconamos as bibliotecas:

```
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:2.2'
implementation 'com.embarkmobile:zxing-android-minimal:1.2.1@aar'
```

No arquivo **AndroidManifest.xml** vamos adicionar a Activity de Captura do QRCode:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Para utilização da câmera, é necessário verificar se há permissão:

```
   private void checkPermission() {
        // Verifica necessidade de verificacao de permissao
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Não há permissão para utilizar a camera!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        CODE_PERMISSION_CAMERA);
            } else {
                // Solicita permissao
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        CODE_PERMISSION_CAMERA);
            }
        }
    }
```

Invocar o leitor de código:

```
 private void openCamera(){
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
       // QR_CODE_MODE: QRCODE , ONE_D_MODE: Codigo de barras
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
```

O resultado volta atravé do método `onActivityResult`:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), contents, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i("CONTENT SCAN ", contents);

        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel
        }
    }
}
```